# upload progress bar

Tags: php, jquery

I use php,jquery .

I have a form where in a user uploads multiple files . when he cliks on submit . everything must get uploaded. and a progress bar must show how much of each image is uploaded.

how do i do the progress bar thing for each image ?

Answer (score 2):

[answer](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/)

check [this](http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/25/howto-php-and-jquery-upload-progress-bar/) also

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Uploadify, does everything you want and more. Easy to implement and can be used in commercial projects. Cheers!